# Setting up query parameters for mountebank testing

Tags: python, rest, testing, mountebank

I want to set-up [mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/) for the end-point `/trends?param1=PT-31`. Following is the way, I am setting up the predicates in the imposter. However, there does not seem to be a match and I do not get a response.

What am I missing?

```
        "predicates": [
            {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "deepEquals": {
                            "path": "/trends",
                            "query": {
                                "param1" : [
                                    "PT-31", "PT-32"
                                ]
                            },
                            "method": "GET",
                            "headers": {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Path `/test` or `/trends`?

Comment: Sorry. It should be `/trends`

Comment: Then please edit your question and correct this typo.

Comment: Done. Updated the path in question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your problem is you are requiring two params in your predicate - PT-31 and PT-32 - which would match a path of /trends?param1=PT-31&param1=PT32 but not /trends?param1=PT-31.

A couple other suggestions, in the hopes that they're useful:

- Because you're using deepEquals, it won't even match /trends?param1=PT-31&param1=PT-32&param1=PT-33. It requires an exact match. If you want to be a bit more flexible, I'd suggest using equals instead
- The outermost "and" predicate is unnecessary. All predicates within a single operator (the "deepEquals") are automatically ANDed together.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Any thoughts on how to match _either_ of `PT-31` and `PT-32` for `param1`?

Comment: Yes, that's what the "or" predicate is, so it'd be something like this:

{
  "or": [
    { "equals": { "query": { "param1": "PT-31" } } },
    { "equals": { "query": { "param1": "PT-32" } } }
  ]
}